# How to have specific data with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here's the link where the data I want is :

[link](https://www.booking.com/hotel/fr/hyatt-regency-paris-etoile.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCA0oTUIMZWx5c2Vlc3VuaW9uSA1YBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAL_5ZqEBsACAdICJDcxYjgyZmI2LTFlYWQtNGZjOS04Y2U2LTkwNTQyZjI5OWY1YtgCBOACAQ;sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3;dest_id=-1456928;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;hpos=1;no_rooms=1;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=popularity;srepoch=1619708145;srpvid=6f6268f8305e011d;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl)

Here's the data I want :

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Gi7.png)

Here's the html :

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC58P.png)

And here's my script :

```
import numpy as np


from time import sleep
from random import randint
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re

headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}

url0 = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCA0oTUIMZWx5c2Vlc3VuaW9uSA1YBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAL_5ZqEBsACAdICJDcxYjgyZmI2LTFlYWQtNGZjOS04Y2U2LTkwNTQyZjI5OWY1YtgCBOACAQ;sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3;dest_id=-1456928;dest_type=city&'
links1 = []

results = requests.get(url0, headers = headers)


soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

links1 = [a['href']  for a in soup.find("div", {"class": "hotellist sr_double_search"}).find_all('a',  href=True)]

root_url = 'https://www.booking.com'
urls1 = [ '{root}{i}'.format(root=root_url, i=i) for i in links1 ]

results = requests.get(urls1[0])

soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

pointfort = [div['data-name-en']  for div in soup.find("div", {"class": "hp_desc_important_facilities clearfix hp_desc_important_facilities--bui"}).find_all('a')]

print(pointfort)
```

But I have an output like this : `[]`

What's wrong with my code ? I would like to store in a list all this data, for each hotel, like this :

[outputdesired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSzu8.png)

Comment: what do youwant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import numpy as np


from time import sleep
from random import randint
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re

headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}

url0 = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCA0oTUIMZWx5c2Vlc3VuaW9uSA1YBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAL_5ZqEBsACAdICJDcxYjgyZmI2LTFlYWQtNGZjOS04Y2U2LTkwNTQyZjI5OWY1YtgCBOACAQ;sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3;dest_id=-1456928;dest_type=city&'
links1 = []

results = requests.get(url0, headers = headers)


soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

links1 = [a['href']  for a in soup.find("div", {"class": "hotellist sr_double_search"}).find_all('a',  href=True)]

root_url = 'https://www.booking.com'
urls1 = [ '{root}{i}'.format(root=root_url, i=i) for i in links1 ]

results = requests.get(urls1[0])

soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

div = soup.find("div", {"class": "hp_desc_important_facilities clearfix hp_desc_important_facilities--bui"})
pointfort = [x['data-name-en'] for x in div.select('div[class*="important_facility"]')]

print(pointfort)
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want ?

```py
## get text of div"data-name-en"
pointfort = [div.text.strip('\n') for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "important_facility"})]
```

or this

```py
## get attributes "data-name-en"
pointfort = [div.attrs['data-name-en'] for div in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "important_facility"})]
```

Comment: Yeah ! But there are doublon : `['Parking', 'Connexion Wi-Fi gratuite', 'Chambres familiales', 'Navette aéroport', 'Chambres non-fumeurs', 'Réception ouverte 24h/24', 'Plateau/bouilloire dans tous les hébergements', 'Bar', 'Parking', 'Connexion Wi-Fi gratuite', 'Chambres familiales', 'Navette aéroport', 'Chambres non-fumeurs', 'Réception ouverte 24h/24', 'Plateau/bouilloire dans tous les hébergements', 'Bar']`

Comment: downside of the page seems also exits these symbols

Answer (score 0):

I think you should spend some time cleaning up your code. This is unworkable for us, but most importantly for you. Your imports are vague, the variable names are vague and re-used, the first Soup search yields unreliable results and it's totally unclear what you're trying to do.

The only way for me to answer your question is to write new code but that's not what Stack Overflow is for.